# The Ubuntu server experiences a system crash when running a program

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, crash, ubuntu-20.04

I am using a NUC with Ubuntu Server deployed to run an MPC controller for controlling my balancing robot. Currently, I'm encountering a troublesome issue: after running this controller, the NUC crashes. The following known symptoms exist:

1. After the crash, the system log contains symbols like "^@^@^@.....", and then the system restarts.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9c4R.jpg)
2. Conditions triggering the crash: staying idle for a period of time or manually tilting the balancing robot to a large pitch angle. Afterward, the kernel crashes.
3. Switching to the LQR controller does not result in a system crash.
   This issue has been perplexing me and my teammates for a long time. What's puzzling is that prior to this, the system crash logs showed symbols like "\0\0\0\0...", and the crashes were intermittent (meaning the MPC controller would run for 3-5 minutes before crashing). The above-mentioned phenomena started occurring after we reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04 Server, and it seems to be a relatively stable occurrence, at least we can trigger it reliably.

Additional information:

1. The MPC controller we are using is generated based on [OCS2](https://github.com/leggedrobotics/ocs2). Could the crash be related to this?
2. The LQR controller, on the other hand, is self-written and does not use third-party packages.

In addressing this issue, my teammates and I have attempted the following:

1. System reinstallation: We have reinstalled the system multiple times. However, in the end, only the triggering conditions for system crashes (such as the large pitch angle and idle time mentioned above) varied. The system still experiences crashes.
2. Changing the mini-computer: We tried replacing several mini-computers, but the system still experienced crashes.
3. Seeking assistance from operations personnel: The operations personnel investigated the Pstore information and suggested that there might be issues with the kernel code and driver components.

I hope everyone can provide other ideas to help us troubleshoot this issue. Thank you all very much for your assistance.